# Pause Vimeo when a div is set to display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, froogaloop

I'm trying to figure out how to write the script to pause a Vimeo video when a div is set to display none. I have the froogalop Vimeo API script linked.

I have the following code for on click but I would like to adjust it so that instead of clicking stop it is automatic on display: none.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
var iframe = $('#vimeo-player')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

$('#stop').click(function(){
    player.api('stop');
});
});
```

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: Use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) object.

Comment: Thank you... could you let me know how I would incorporate into my code above?